# The array saved by UserDefaults in the dictionary type disappears

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The array saved in UIPickerView as a dictionary type UserDefaults in EventViewController disappears when it returns to ViewController.
Save the character put in UITextField with @IBAction of Button.
I want to keep the saved string.
I don't know the solution.
Xcode 12.2

```
class EventViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var partsPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var partsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuTextField: UITextField!
```

Put a dictionary type array

```
    var menuDataList: [String: [String]] = [
        "Leg": ["Squat","Leg press","Leg extension"],
        "Back": ["Deadlift","Bent over row","Chinning"],
        "Chest": ["Barbell bench press","Dumbbell bench press","Incline Dumbbell Bench Press"]
    ]
    var partsDataList: [String] = [
        "Leg","Back","Chest"
    ]
    var selectedParts = ""
```

Delegate settings

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        partsPickerView.delegate = self
        partsPickerView.dataSource = self
        menuPickerView.delegate = self
        menuPickerView.dataSource = self
        menuTextField.delegate = self
        
        partsPickerView.tag = 1
        menuPickerView.tag = 2
        selectedParts = partsDataList[0]
    }
```

Instantiate UserDefaults

```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let keyMenuDataList = "newMenu"

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

Add event button

```
    @IBAction func didTapAddMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (menuTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true == false) {
            
            let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: "保存されました。", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "閉じる", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }
            okAlert.addAction(closeAction)
            present(okAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            if let text = menuTextField.text {
                
                menuDataList[selectedParts]?.append(text)
                
                menuDataList = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "keyMenuDataList") as? [String: [String]] ?? [:]
                
                userDefaults.set(menuDataList, forKey: "keyMenuDataList")
                
            }
            
        } else {
            
            let ngAlert = UIAlertController(title: "テキストが空です。", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "閉じる", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }
            ngAlert.addAction(closeAction)
            present(ngAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
        menuPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        
    }
```

UIPickerView settings

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 1{
            return partsDataList.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2{
            return menuDataList[selectedParts]?.count ?? 0
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ picker: UIPickerView,
                    titleForRow row: Int,
                    forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if picker.tag == 1 {
            return partsDataList[row]
        } else if picker.tag == 2 {
            return menuDataList[selectedParts]?[row] ?? ""
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    didSelectRow row: Int,
                    inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            partsLabel.text = partsDataList[row]
            selectedParts = partsDataList[row]
            menuPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            menuLabel.text = menuDataList[selectedParts]?[row] ?? ""
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: `true == false` is pointless. It will always be false. When dealing with optional `Bool` you have 3 possible results `true`, `false` or `nil`. So to be clear just add `== whatever`. If you want to check is it is empty  `if menuTextField.text?.isEmpty == true`. Note that UITextField `text` property default value is an empty string therefore it will NEVER return `nil` so `if menuTextField.text!.isEmpty`. Btw UIKeyControl has an instance property called `hasText` exactly for this purpose. `if menuTextField.hasText { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: if menuTextField.hasText {
…String was still not saved.

Comment: This was already asked and answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65088938/3118886

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I moved this to viewDidLoad and solved it.

```
menuDataList = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "keyMenuDataList") as? [String: [String]] ?? [:]
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        partsPickerView.delegate = self
        partsPickerView.dataSource = self
        menuPickerView.delegate = self
        menuPickerView.dataSource = self
        menuTextField.delegate = self
        
        partsPickerView.tag = 1
        menuPickerView.tag = 2
        selectedParts = partsDataList[0]

        menuDataList = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "keyMenuDataList") as? [String: [String]] ?? [:]

    }
```

```
    @IBAction func didTapAddMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (menuTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true == false) {
            
            let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: "保存されました。", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "閉じる", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }
            okAlert.addAction(closeAction)
            present(okAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            if let text = menuTextField.text {
                
                menuDataList[selectedParts]?.append(text)
                                
                userDefaults.set(menuDataList, forKey: "keyMenuDataList")
                
            }
            
        } else {
            
            let ngAlert = UIAlertController(title: "テキストが空です。", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "閉じる", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }
            ngAlert.addAction(closeAction)
            present(ngAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
        menuPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see your code:

```
menuDataList = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "keyMenuDataList") as? [String: [String]] ?? [:]
userDefaults.set(menuDataList, forKey: "keyMenuDataList")
```

You assigned the `userDefaults` to `menuDataList`. But when you first get value for key from `userDefaults`, it's value is a nil. So your code is like:

```
menuDataList = [:];
userDefaults.set([:], forKey: "keyMenuDataList")
```

Your see, the `userDefaults` will always be [:] and you clean the `menuDataList` again and again.
This code: `menuDataList = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "keyMenuDataList") as? [String: [String]] ?? [:]` is useless, you can just remove it and try again.

Comment: Thank you for comment.
menuPickerView is empty.
Is the method different?

Comment: Do you have your SourceCode on Git? It really seems like you are missing something...

Comment: @uskitm What do you mean `menuPickerView is empty`? Do you mean `menuDataList`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the UserDefaults keys?

You need to call this function on every time you launch your app again.

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [String : Any])
```

Comment: I put it in but it doesn't change.userDefaults.register(defaults: ["keyMenuDataList": "Squat"])